# Как создать объектный или исполняемый файл?

Tags: компиляция

У меня вопрос: как программно создать объектный или даже сразу исполняемый файл?

Т е, допустим, у меня есть язык программирования свой, и я хочу, чтобы он был компилируемым.

К интерпретируемым и байт-кодным языкам у меня нет вопросов, поскольку в обоих случаях задействуется некий интерпретатор, а не сама ОС. Т е я могу запросто описать синтаксис, правила считывания байт-кода, и т д. Сам формат исполняемого файла и его исполнение находится под моим контролем, я могу этим управлять, я могу это понимать.

А вот как создать (программно) исполняемый файл ELF/PE/COFF - я не знаю.

Конечно, кто-то скажет про LLVM. Но, тут возникает вопрос: а ведь как-то и сам LLVM транслирует LLVM-IR в исполняемый файл. Тот же GCC, компиляторы ассемблера (GNU AS, NASM, YASM и т д) вообще обходятся без этого вашего LLVM. Как? Как устроена компиляция в "нативный" код, понятный самой операционной системе?

Comment: есть спецификации по структуре и наполнению исполняемого файла. просто следуешь ей и все

Comment: GNU AS, NASM, YASM сами создают только объектные файлы. Для создания исполняемого файла они используют линкер.

Comment: ну так и вопрос: как создать *объектный или исполняемый* файл

Comment: @RandomDice779, [например](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/817-3677/chapter6-46512/index.html). Тут указано где и какие данные должны располагаться.

Comment: @RandomDice779 которткий ответ - по спецификации. Гуглите спецификацию, например, COFF, импортируете нужные структуры из windows.h, формируете файл. Аналогично с исполняемым файлом.